# Smooth display of a grid without jerks on console

Tags: c#, console

I'm making this pacman console based game, in which there is a 40x40 board. There are pacmans and enemies on the board eating food. pacman is represented by 0 and enemy by #. Everytime there position changes the display function gets called, which in current logic, after every second clears the whole console and reprints each element on the board.. but this way, there are these jerks whenever whole board gets displayed. Kindly tell me a better way to achieve a smooth motion of paacman and enemy, ideally i should only change only the position of pacman and enemy, but i need to clear the console in order to show the grid on the same spot, otherwise it will just keep scrolling down. The code for display function is below:

```
public static void display()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
                {
                    bool packFound = false;
                    bool enmFound = false;

                    foreach (Packman element in myVers.packmans)
                    {
                        if (element.x == i && element.y == j)
                        {
                            packFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (Packman element in myVers.enemys)
                    {
                        if (element.x == i && element.y == j)
                        {
                            enmFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (packFound == true)
                    {
                        Console.Write('0');
                        myVers.board[i, j] = ' ';
                    }
                    else if (enmFound == true)
                    {
                        myVers.board[i, j] = ' ';
                        Console.Write('#');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(myVers.board[i, j]);
                    }
                }
                Console.Write('\n');
            }
            //Console.Write("\nFood Count " + myVers.foodCount + "\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you would only redraw the characters that really changed? Maybe with use of [Console.SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try building the `String` for the board first then pass the whole thing to the console at one time.  Still perform the clear operation.

This would be a job for:
[`String Builder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public static void display()
    {
        var boardStr = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
            {
                bool packFound = false;
                bool enmFound = false;

                foreach (Packman element in myVers.packmans)
                {
                    if (element.x == i && element.y == j)
                    {
                        packFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                foreach (Packman element in myVers.enemys)
                {
                    if (element.x == i && element.y == j)
                    {
                        enmFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (packFound == true)
                {
                   boardStr.Append("0");
                    myVers.board[i, j] = ' ';
                }
                else if (enmFound == true)
                {
                    myVers.board[i, j] = ' ';
                    boardStr.Append("#");
                }
                else
                {
                    boardStr.Append(myVers.board[i, j].ToString());
                }
            }
            boardStr.Append("\n");
        }
        //Console.Write("\nFood Count " + myVers.foodCount + "\n");
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write(boardStr.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Tried this too, but still there are some jerks. Marko's solution is the way to go..